# How to hide/remove time row in Kendo Scheduler UI in angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-scheduler

I work over a Project with the Kendo UI and try to figure out how to remove or hide the Time-Row from the Scheduler in angular 6.

here is my code with sample date in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brn2en-rtbgjt

I want to remove or hide the second row: "11:00 AM"

Comment: If you do not want to show the time row, I thing you should use  kendo-scheduler-month-view instead of kendo-scheduler-timeline-month-view. ``` <kendo-scheduler-month-view columnWidth="20px" >
            </kendo-scheduler-month-view>```

Comment: @MarissaFernandes I would like to display all days of the month for each employee in a row. and this does not work with <kendo-scheduler-month-view> tag.